# Split a string at occurence of a space

Tags: javascript

I have strings like "test-example - one" I need to get the characters before the space. I can split it using

```
this.value.substring(0, this.value.indexOf('-')
```

but it won't work if I substitute a `' '` for the  `'-'`

Comment: Something else is going on, it should be fine.  Paste this into your console and run it - it will return "test-example": `var x = "test-example - one"; x.substring(0, x.indexOf(' '))`

Comment: Try `"a b c d".split(/\s+/)` as an example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript split String with white space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425637/javascript-split-string-with-white-space)

Answer (score 0):

Are you returning the result of `substring()` to a variable? If I run this, it returns what was expected...

```
var s = 'test-example - one';
var s2 = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(' '));
console.log(s2);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zg6x7ywt/

Comment: Because it's not really an answer - just a clarification that what the OP has should work.  Clearly it doesn't work otherwise they wouldn't be asking, so the problem lies elsewhere (and the question currently has 2 close votes as such).  It would have been better as a comment.

Comment: Gotcha. Oh the politics of SO