# How to splice several strings

Tags: javascript

Good evening, I am attempting to extract multiple variables in a line which is separated by tabs.
Here is an example of the lines:

```
ALPRAZOLAM XANAX ANXIETY F41.1
ALPRAZOLAM XANAX DEPRESSION F33.0
```

How would one go about extracting the individual values from this line?
Thank you!

Comment: Split by line break, iterate over the list of strings and split each one by tab (or whitespace). https://stackoverflow.com/q/96428/218196

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript split String with white space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425637/javascript-split-string-with-white-space)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const x = `ALPRAZOLAM XANAX ANXIETY F41.1
ALPRAZOLAM XANAX DEPRESSION F33.0`;

const y = x.split("\n").flatMap(el => el.split(" "));

console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split it on the basis of space and adding them into an array like this

```
var string = "ALPRAZOLAM XANAX DEPRESSION F33.0";
var array = string.split( "\n" );
console.log(array);
```

For splitting it on the basis of new line and whitespace use this

```
var string = "ALPRAZOLAM XANAX DEPRESSION F33.0";
var array = string.split(/\s+/);
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Done it with plain JS

```js
var input = "ALPRAZOLAM XANAX ANXIETY F41.1";
var arr = [];

arr = input.split(' ');

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```