# Split Full Name to First Name and Last Name in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this `var fullName = 'Muhammad Ali'`, what I want to do is split the First Name and Last name from it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What about using [`.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript split String with white space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425637/javascript-split-string-with-white-space)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For simple cases, use `.split()`. Usually a simple google search can help you.

```js
let fullName = 'Muhammad Ali'
let formattedName = fullName.split(" ")
console.log(formattedName)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .split() method to split the string to an array based on spaces in the string. I would use caution with this as names can differ in length and have more than one space.